# Как установить другую иконку сайта в консоли WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Начиная с версии 4.3, в WordPress появилась возможность задать иконку сайта через меню консоли: "Внешний вид->Настроить->Свойства сайта->Иконка сайта". Иконка должна быть квадратной, не менее 512 пикселей по ширине и высоте.

Однако, при работе с сайтом хотелось бы иметь разные иконки для внешних страниц сайта и его административных страниц (консоли). Так в браузере удобнее различать вкладки, относящиеся к данному сайту.

Как установить другую иконку сайта в консоли WordPress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Начиная с версии 4.3, в WordPress добавлен фильтр `get_site_icon_url`, с помощью которого можно управлять выводом иконок.

В `functions.php` надо вставить такой код:

```
/**
 * Filter to modify favicon in admin area.
 *
 * @param string $url URL of favicon.
 * @param int $size Size of favicon.
 * @param int $blog_id Blog id.
 *
 * @return false|string
 */
function get_site_icon_url_filter( $url, $size, $blog_id ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $switched_blog = false;

        if ( is_multisite() && ! empty( $blog_id ) && get_current_blog_id() !== (int) $blog_id ) {
            switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
            $switched_blog = true;
        }

        switch ( $blog_id ) {
            case 0:
                $site_icon_id = 0000; // Here we set admin-favicon.png id.
                break;
            default:
                $site_icon_id = get_option( 'site_icon' );
        }

        if ( $site_icon_id ) {
            if ( $size >= 512 ) {
                $size_data = 'full';
            } else {
                $size_data = array( $size, $size );
            }
            $url = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $site_icon_id, $size_data );
        }

        if ( $switched_blog ) {
            restore_current_blog();
        }
    }

    return $url;
}

add_filter( 'get_site_icon_url', 'get_site_icon_url_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Этот фильтр в примере работает только в административной части сайта, проверяя `is_admin()`.

В случае мультисайта производится переключение на запрашиваемый блог. Внутри `switch ( $blog_id )` можно установить разные админ-иконки для разных блогов мультисайта. `$blog_id` равен 0 только в случае обычной установки WordPress.

В строке `$site_icon_id = 0000;` вместо 0000 нужно вставить id иконки для административной части сайта. Иконка должна быть загружена в библиотеку мультимедиа например, как файл .png размером 512x512. Узнать id можно, войдя в режим редактирования файла в библиотеке. В адресной строке браузера будет что-то вроде `site.ru/wp-admin/post.php?post=0000&action=edit`, где 0000 - id иконки.

В принципе, приведенный в примере фильтр можно использовать в самых разных случаях, вплоть до того, что выводить отдельную иконку на любой выбранной странице сайта.